# transpose a columns to row in a list of dataframes and write it to a new dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes and need to transpose each column in a dataframe and create a new dataframe.  Here is a reproducible example. So I need to create 4 dataframes of size 500 rows and 100 columns by transposing 4 columns for each dataframe in the list.

```
  # simulate list of 500 dataframes where each dataframe has 100 rows and 4 columns

    mat<-as.matrix(diag(c(1,2,3,4)))

  dat<-list()
     for (i in 1:500){
   dat[[i]]<-as.data.frame(mvrnorm(100,rep(0,4),mat))
                     }

 # I need an output that would look something like this - transpose first column in each of the 500 
 dataframes and combine into a single dataframe. I am showing for 3 dataframes in a list.

 t(dat[[1]][,1])
 t(dat[[2]][,1])
 t(dat[[3]][,1])


dat.1<-rbind(t(dat[[1]][,1]),t(dat[[2]][,1]),t(dat[[3]][,1]))
 head(dat.1)

# Tried doing this function for transposing first column of each of the 500 dataframes in the list
 # but gives an error that "dim(X) must have positive length ".
    dat.1<-apply(dat,1,function(x){t(dat[[x]][,1])})
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are going for:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(dat, `[`, , 1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
result <- do.call(rbind,lapply(dat, `[[`, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `tidyverse`, we can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(dat, `[`, 1)
```